# How to manage hardcoded paths in custom InfoPath forms for different environments (dev, staging, release)?

Tags: development, infopath, custom-form, form, environment

When you create custom InfoPath forms for your SharePoint components (lists, workflow tasks or initialization form etc) all web references point to InfoPath Designer. Create one from a blank form and stuff it where it needs be.

But how about forms that have data connections that come from SharePoint lists? To be able to create the `.xsn` file, you need to provide a list that the designer can query to know the returned fields from that and add them as a secondary connection (to build the schema).

But the problem is that inside the generated `.xsn`, all source files point to that list (by URL, GUIDs etc) - values are hard coded.

But when you try to deploy to staging or prod, those URLs and GUIDs are different and your custom form won't work anymore.

My question: **How can you remove all hard coded values added by InfoPath Designer inside the `.xsn` file so that you can reuse the forms with no modifications on different sites or environments?** Modifying the forms by hand to change there hard coded paths to match each environment would be a major pain.